# How can I get the first image of a thread using nextcord api?

Tags: discord, chatbot, nextcord

I want to be able to get the first/last image of a thread in discord using nextcord.

I think I have to go through the channel/thread history but then how do I get the image out of the message? is an URL that I have to `request.get`?

```py
   if message.flags.has_thread:
      async for m in message.thread.history(limit=100, oldest_first=True):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this as per your code:

```
if message.flags.has_thread:
    async for m in message.thread.history(limit=100, oldest_first=True):
        if m.attachments:
            return m.attachments[0].url


first_image_url = await first_image_from_thread(channel_id, thread_id)
if first_image_url:
    response = requests.get(first_image_url)
    with open('first_image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    print("Downloaded first image from thread...")
else:
    print("No image found in thread...")
```

In this, first_image_from_thread will be your function where you will pass parameter of **channel_id** & **thread_id**.

You can also iterate through the attachments and check if it's image with it's file type like `attachment.file_type.endswith(".jpeg")`. If it's image you seeing then use "url" property to get image url and use "requests" module to download the image.